# How to use proc mean to average only last n rows of a table?

Tags: sas

I have a table with 50 rows. I want to take an average of every numerical column of the whole table, the the most recent 40 rows, and most recent 30 rows. The rows have a date identifier that goes in decreasing order from oldest to newest at the bottom.

Does anyone know how to do this with proc mean or proc sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the analysis groups using a data step view and the firstobs data set option.

```
data analysis;
   set sashelp.class(in=in1) sashelp.class(in=in2 firstobs=6) sashelp.class(in=in3 firstobs=12);
   select;
      when(in1) group=1;
      when(in2) group=2;
      when(in3) group=3;
      end;
   run;
proc means;
   class group;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `proc sql` with a derived table that runs a correlated count subquery used in outer query's conditional average calculation. Below runs for three numeric columns, extend it to fit actual dataset:

```sql
proc sql;
    CREATE NewDataSet AS

    (SELECT Avg(main.NumCol1) As FullAvgNumCol1, Avg(main.NumCol2) As FullAvgNumCol2,  
            Avg(main.NumCol3) As FullAvgNumCol3,

            Avg(CASE WHEN main.RowCount <= 40 
                THEN main.NumCol1 ELSE NULL END) AS Top40AvgNumCol1,
            Avg(CASE WHEN main.RowCount <= 40 
                THEN main.NumCol2 ELSE NULL END) AS Top40AvgNumCol2,
            Avg(CASE WHEN main.RowCount <= 40 
                THEN main.NumCol3 ELSE NULL END) AS Top40AvgNumCol3,

            Avg(CASE WHEN main.RowCount >= main.FullCount - 30 
                THEN main.NumCol1 ELSE NULL END) AS Bottom30AvgNumCol1,
            Avg(CASE WHEN main.RowCount >= main.FullCount - 30 
                THEN main.NumCol2 ELSE NULL END) AS Bottom30AvgNumCol2,
            Avg(CASE WHEN main.RowCount >= main.FullCount - 30 
                THEN main.NumCol3 ELSE NULL END) AS Bottom30AvgNumCol3

    FROM 
        (SELECT sub.NumCol1, sub.NumCol2, sub.NumCol3,
                (SELECT Count(*) FROM DataSet sub 
                 WHERE sub.Date <= d.Date) As RowCount,
                (SELECT Count(*) FROM DataSet) As FullCount
         FROM DataSet d) AS main);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hopefully a simple alternative. As your data are ordered already, you could create a date counter that counts away from the most recent day then use a where statement in your proc means.

Create some toy data - random dates, and 3 numeric columns.

```
data one;

  do i = 1 to 50;

    date = 20000+i;
    num1 = rand("Poisson", 6);
    num2 = rand("uniform");
    num3 = i*(i-1);
    output;

  end;

  format date date9.;
  drop i;
run;
```

Create counter to be referenced by proc means.
Most recent day has value 1, then oldest day has value 50.

```
data two;
set one nobs= nobs;

  datecount = nobs - _N_ + 1;

run;
```

Use where statement in proc means - datecount =< 30 says you want the 30 most recent days.

```
proc means data = two ( where = ( datecount =< 30));
  var num1 num2 num3;
  output out = averages (drop = _type_ _freq_) 
  mean = Mean1 Mean2 Mean3;
run;
```